# How To Get All UserID in telegram group using pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

so I want to make a bot that can mention all members of the group how do I do it? Or in other words, how do you find out all userIDs of group members on telegram using pyTelegramBotAPI?

Comment: Hi Naufal - welcome to StackOverflow - please read this article about how to write good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I'd suggest mentioning what you've tried until now and did not work for you.